# Cross Verification of a Probability Homework Problem

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Verifying the solution to an exercise I am doing from a course on Probability. My answer does not match with the given solution :/

### Question

A particle starts at the origin and moves to and from on a straight line. At any move it jumps either 1 unit to the right or 1 unit to the left each with probability $\frac12$ . All successive moves are independent. Given that the particle is at the origin at the completion of the 6th move, find the probability that it never occupied a position to the left of the origin during previous moves.

### My solution

Let $A$ be the event that the particle never occupied a position to the left of the origin. Let $B$ be the event that the particle is at the origin after 6 moves. The question is then asking for $Pr(A|B)$. Applying Baye's theorem, we have

$$Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(B|A)  \times Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$$

Since all paths are equally likely $Pr(A)$ can be computed as $\sum_{i+j=6}C(i,j)$ where $C(n,k)$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of Catalan's Triangle. Thus, $Pr(A) = \frac{20}{2^6}$. $Pr(B)$ is simply $\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{2^6} = \frac{20}{2^6}$

Thus, we have that $Pr(A|B) = Pr(B|A) = \frac{5}{20} = \frac{1}{4}$

But the exercise claims that the solution is $\frac{1}{2^4}$

What is my mistake? Any help or hints will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I suspect there's something wrong with Pr(A)

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate the probability directly. Rows are the moves, columns are the locations, entries are the probability of being in this location on this move without ever having moved to the left of $0$.
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline 1&&\frac12\\2&\frac14&&\frac14\\3&&\frac28&&\frac18\\4&\frac 2{16}&&\frac3{16}&&\frac1{16}\\5&&\frac5{32}&&\frac4{32}&&\frac1{32}\\6&\frac5{64}&&\frac9{64}&&\frac5{64}&&\frac1{64} \end{array}$$

The probability that the particle never moved left of the origin is $$Pr(A) = \frac{5 + 9 + 5 + 1}{64} = \frac{20}{64}$$ and $$Pr(B|A) = \frac{\dfrac5{64}}{\dfrac{20}{64}}=\frac5{20}$$
Your calculation of $\Pr(B) = \dfrac{6 \choose 3}{64} = \frac {20}{64}$ looks correct to me, so $$Pr(A|B) = \frac{\dfrac 5{20}\times\dfrac{20}{64}}{\dfrac{20}{64}} = \dfrac 5{20}$$
as you calculated.

It appears your only mistake is believing the "official" answer was correct.